# Django + Celery + Redis: kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

Although celery reports no problems at start and says it successfully connected to redis (see log), I get this error running `celery inspect ping`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 446, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 201, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 217, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 134, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/control.py", line 136, in inspect
    replies = inspect._request(action,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 106, in _request
    return self._prepare(self.app.control.broadcast(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 741, in broadcast
    return self.mailbox(conn)._broadcast(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 328, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 895, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 450, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It is a docker-compose app with the redis initiated in docker-compose.yml, so we can see the logs from all containers. Also we can see the celery-beat tasks run successfully, but I want to call task.delay() in one of the views, and there it fails with the same error. Logs:

```
db_1           | 
db_1           | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1           | 
db_1           | 2022-08-18 09:16:02.923 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 64-bit
db_1           | 2022-08-18 09:16:02.923 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1           | 2022-08-18 09:16:02.923 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1           | 2022-08-18 09:16:02.930 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
frontend_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
frontend_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
redis_1        | 1:C 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.869 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1        | 1:C 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.869 # Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1        | 1:C 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.869 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
db_1           | 2022-08-18 09:16:02.942 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-18 09:13:45 UTC
frontend_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.870 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
db_1           | 2022-08-18 09:16:02.947 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
frontend_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.871 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.871 # Server initialized
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.871 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
frontend_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * The AOF directory appendonlydir doesn't exist
frontend_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.0.0
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * RDB age 134 seconds
frontend_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * RDB memory usage when created 1.18 Mb
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 2, keys expired: 0.
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.22.0
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
redis_1        | 1:M 18 Aug 2022 09:16:02.872 * Ready to accept connections
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
frontend_1     | 2022/08/18 09:16:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
celery-beat_1  | [2022-08-18 09:16:05,012: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
celery_1       |  
celery_1       |  -------------- celery@934c4c8d4628 v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
celery_1       | --- ***** ----- 
celery_1       | -- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2022-08-18 09:16:05
celery_1       | - *** --- * --- 
celery_1       | - ** ---------- [config]
celery_1       | - ** ---------- .> app:         MyFavouriteSite:0x7f2188204a00
celery_1       | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379//
celery_1       | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/
celery_1       | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
celery_1       | -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
celery_1       | --- ***** ----- 
celery_1       |  -------------- [queues]
celery_1       |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
celery_1       |                 
celery_1       | 
celery_1       | [tasks]
celery_1       |   . app1.tasks.task1
celery_1       |   . app2.tasks.task1
celery_1       | 
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:16:05,516: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379//
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:16:05,519: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:16:06,530: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:16:06,614: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
celery_1       |             leak, never use this setting in production environments!
celery_1       |   warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
celery_1       | 
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:16:06,614: INFO/MainProcess] celery@934c4c8d4628 ready.
celery-beat_1  | [2022-08-18 09:30:00,104: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task1_name_in_settings (app1.tasks.task1)
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:30:00,123: INFO/MainProcess] Task app1.tasks.task1[09c3c690-a379-4a30-a7b4-25cfa57d679a] received
celery_1       | [2022-08-18 09:30:00,143: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task app1.tasks.task1[09c3c690-a379-4a30-a7b4-25cfa57d679a] succeeded in 0.0180537269989145s: None
```

Comment: I faced the same issue and was getting the same error, and what helped me resolve the issue was removing the extra concurrency option that is in the Celery tutorial config file.

Comment: For the next person who might have a challenge on this problem and they encounter such a problem you can check if the redis server is installed and if it's installed check if it is running.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I didn't have the following code in `MySiteName/__init__.py` (MySiteName is a folder that also contains settings.py and celery.py)

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Adding it fixed my issue. (celery inspect ping still produces it, probably, because of misconfig, but I can run the task I want in my view)