# OperationalError at / [Errno 111] Connection refused with Django and Celery

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, gunicorn

As the title suggest, I'm having

```
OperationalError at /
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I'm using Django with Celery and Redis as Broker. The issue happens only when I'm using gunicorn with the command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 Lab.wsgi`. Everything work with the Django internal server

I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73400719/django-celery-redis-kombu-exceptions-operationalerror-errno-111-connecti) but it didn't work for me

From the stack error it seems it's trying to use amqp when I'm using Redis with Celery.

In Django on my settings.py I have

```
REDIS_HOST = "172.20.1.2"
REDIS_PORT = "6379"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://" + REDIS_HOST + ":" + REDIS_PORT + "/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
BROKER_TRASPORT_PROTOCOL = {"visibility_timeout":3600}
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTET = ["application/json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
```

In `celery.py` I have also tried

```
app = Celery('Lab', backend='redis://' + settings.REDIS_HOST + ':' + settings.REDIS_PORT + '/0', 
             broker= "redis://" + settings.REDIS_HOST + ":" + settings.REDIS_PORT + "/0")
```

So I can't understand

For some reason Celery is using the default broker

```
 During handling of the above exception ('ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'), another exception occurred:
/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py, line 472, in _reraise_as_library_errors
                yield
     …
Local vars
Variable    Value
ChannelError    <class 'kombu.exceptions.OperationalError'>
ConnectionError     <class 'kombu.exceptions.OperationalError'>
self    <Connection: amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672// at 0x7fb90c79af20>
```

Error stack

```
Internal Server Error: /celery-progress/01f2ab7b-5b25-4bda-901f-50cedb4d4a69/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery_progress/views.py", line 10, in get_progress
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(progress.get_info()), content_type='application/json')
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery_progress/backend.py", line 64, in get_info
    task_meta = self.result._get_task_meta()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 438, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 608, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
COM selected /dev/ttyUSB0
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 472, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 459, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 318, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 941, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 867, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 203, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/dashboard/views.py", line 34, in home
    form_info = form.save()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 542, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 892, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
    return [
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/dashboard/models.py", line 115, in send_task_creation
    start_serial_acquisition.delay(instance.pk, porta_COM)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 444, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 798, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 517, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in publish
    return _publish(
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 563, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 195, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 218, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 34, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 234, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 960, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 458, in _ensure_connection
    with ctx():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/lab/dashboardlab/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 476, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```