# How to bypass the TTL of 30 seconds while waiting response of post request from external server

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openai-api

I am building a view in Django , which will send a POST request to chat-gpt API, the problem that I am facing that the response from chat-gpt is taking more than 30 seconds (we are having a long prompts)
the idea that I have in mind is:

1. The client sends a request to the server.
2. The server writes the request to a message queue and returns a
   message ID to the client.
3. Another worker is listening to the message queue. It retrieves the
   request from the queue, sends it to OpenAI,and then writes the
   response back to the message queue.
4. The client periodically sends requests to the server to ask for the response using the previously received message ID.
5. The server responds with "pending" until it finds the response in the message queue, at which point it returns the actual response to the client.

the problem is that I have no idea how to achieve that ...
I am using gke for hosting the application, I already have some cronjob using some views as well
any idea how to deal with this will be so much appreciated
here is an example of the view request:

```py
import openai
from app.forms_prompt import PromptForm
from app.models import ModelName
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


@login_required
def form_prompt(request: HttpRequest, pk: int) -> HttpResponse:
    instance = get_object_or_404(ModelName, pk=pk)
    openai.api_key = settings.OPENAI_KEY
    form = PromptForm(request.POST or None, instance=setkeyword)
    # check if form data is valid
    if form.is_valid():
        prompt = form.cleaned_data["text"]
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=[
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
            ],
        )
        instance.specific_field = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
        form.save()
        return redirect("view_instance_name", instance.pk)
    return render(request, "view_prompt_name.html", context)
```

any suggestion how to follow the solution, will be very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the response from chat-gpt is taking more than 30 seconds (we are having a long prompts)

That means you need an asynchronous processing, which is a common pattern in distributed systems to handle long-running tasks or slow external dependencies.

Your current setup is:

```
Client --(HTTP POST)--> Django View --(API Call)--> External Service (GPT API)
```

To implement your idea, you might consider [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) for task processing, [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) as the message broker, and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for handling HTTP requests.

```
Client ------(HTTP POST)------> Django View ------(Message)------> RabbitMQ
                                      |                               |
                                      |<----------(Polling)-----------|
                                      |                               |
                                      |-----------(Task)------------->| Celery -----(API Call)----> External Service
                                      |                       b       |                              |
                                      |<----------(Response)----------|<-----------------------------|
```

Install Celery in your Django project and set up RabbitMQ as the message broker ([bundle](https://pypi.org/project/celery/#bundles): `pip install celery[redis]`), and configure it to use RabbitMQ as the message broker: create a new file named `celery.py` in your main Django app directory:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_project.settings')

app = Celery('your_project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Then create a [Celery task](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html) to handle the GPT API call:

```py
# tasks.py in one of your apps
import openai
from django.conf import settings
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def get_gpt_response(prompt, message_id):
    openai.api_key = settings.OPENAI_KEY
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )
    # Store the response in your database against the message_id
    # rest of your code
```

Modify your Django view to enqueue the task and return a message ID to the client.

```py
from app.tasks import get_gpt_response
from uuid import uuid4
# other imports/code

@login_required
def form_prompt(request: HttpRequest, pk: int) -> HttpResponse:
    instance = get_object_or_404(ModelName, pk=pk)
    form = PromptForm(request.POST or None, instance=setkeyword)
    if form.is_valid():
        prompt = form.cleaned_data["text"]
        message_id = str(uuid4())  # Generate a unique message ID
        get_gpt_response.delay(prompt, message_id)  # Enqueue the task
        # Store the message ID and initial status in your database
        return JsonResponse({'message_id': message_id})  # Return the message ID to the client
    return render(request, "view_prompt_name.html", context)
```

Create a new Django view to handle polling requests from the client, using [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) .

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
# other import/code

def check_status(request: HttpRequest, message_id: str) -> HttpResponse:
    # Retrieve the status and possibly the response from your database using the message_id
    # 
    # If response is ready, return it to the client
    # else return a 'pending' status
    #
```

Now, the [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) of 30 seconds should no longer be a problem, since the client will keep polling the server for the response, and the server will respond with the actual result once it is ready.

See also:

- "[Celery using RabbitMQ](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/rabbitmq.html)" and "[Getting Started with Celery & RabbitMQ](https://medium.com/geekculture/getting-started-with-celery-243429df53b9)" from [Hitesh Mishra](https://twitter.com/hiteshmishra708)
- "[Celery First steps with Django](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)"

---

> When arrived to the `get_gpt_response.delay(prompt, message_id) # Enqueue the task`, I got this message, `error: kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` I am wondering if I correctly initiated celery.

The error `kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` you are encountering is typically associated with Celery being unable to connect to the message broker (like RabbitMQ or Redis). That could be due to several reasons such as the broker service not running, incorrect broker URL, or network issues.

The solution on [GitHub `celery/kombu` issue 1582 mentions](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1582#issuecomment-1214322443) adds the `broker` and `backend` settings to the Celery configuration, and makes sure the Redis server is running.
You may need to adapt your Celery configuration similarly.

```py
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_project.settings')

# Use Redis as the broker if it exists
app = Celery('your_project', broker="redis://localhost:6379", backend="redis://localhost:6379")

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
broker_url = "redis://localhost:6379"
app.conf.broker_url = BROKER_URL
CELERY_BROKER_URL = BROKER_URL

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # any periodic tasks you have
}

@app.task
def debug_task():
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

---

The [OP ladhari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792426/ladhari) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320495/how-to-bypass-the-ttl-of-30-seconds-while-waiting-response-of-post-request-from/77338101#comment136387136_77338101) making it work, using "[Django + Celery + Redis: `kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401366/6309)"

```py
import openai
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import ResponseOpenAI

def get_gpt_response(prompt, message_id):
    openai.api_key = settings.OPENAI_KEY
    
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        ]
    )
    
    print(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
    
    message_data = {
        "message_id": message_id,
        "status": "finished",
        "response": response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"],
    }
    
    ResponseOpenAI.objects.create(**message_data)
    
    return JsonResponse(
        {"message_id": message_id},
        {"status": "finished"}
    )
```

Comment: first , I want to thank you for this detailed and very clear answer and it answers exactly to my question! really kind of you
just one more detail, when you say # Store the message ID and initial status in your database , do you mean I should create a new model in django to handle saving the response and its ID ?

Comment: @ladhari Yes, exactly. Creating a new Django model would be a structured way to store the message ID, initial status, and eventually the response from the external service. That model can have fields like `message_id`, `status`, and `response` to track the progress and hold the data of each task.

Comment: thank you so much, I am working on it now !

Comment: Sorry for bothering again when arrived to the get_gpt_response.delay(prompt, message_id)  # Enqueue the task, I got this message error: kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
I am wondering if I correctly initiated celery

Comment: a small search in internet, i found this: https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1582#issuecomment-1214322443

Comment: @ladhari Good catch. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I agree that the answer is very good but, and please, understand my words, I think GCP provides different products that could help in implementing a more cloud native, resilient, and scalable solution. Good answer in any way mate.

Comment: @jccampanero i will test your solution as well, I do not know if I can accept both answers or no, I am so thankful for your great help

Comment: still facing the same error despite the update that you did ... , I will try to debug further

Comment: @ladhari No problem, let me know what you will find out. Or do not hesitate to ask a separate question with your current setup and error message.

Comment: @VonC finally I resolved the error by using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401366/5792426 and yours as well,
about the check_status method , it is not clear how can I fetch the status, besides it is always showing the json response with the message_id only
here my method:

Comment: def get_gpt_response(prompt, message_id,):
    openai.api_key = settings.OPENAI_KEY
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )
    print(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
    message_data = {
        "message_id": message_id,
        "status": "finished",
        "response": response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"],
    }
    ResponseOpenAI.objects.create(**message_data)
    return JsonResponse(
        {"message_id": message_id}, {"status": "finished"}
    )

Comment: @ladhari Great, well done! I have included your code (reformatted) in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC , thank you for all your efforts, the task seems to not be executed at all, I have included a breakpoints in tasks.py to see if the task is called by the worker but nothing, I keep just having the json response from the view with the message_id
is there something missing?

Comment: @ladhari Can you join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255762/77320495-ttl ?

Comment: @VonC sorry for late reply, i caught flu lately and I was in very bad condition, can we have a chat session if you do not mind?

Comment: @ladhari Sure, hop over to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1204/vonc, and starts your messages with `@VonC`.

Comment: thank you for such fast reply and help the room seems to be frozen: This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.

Comment: @ladhari OK try https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255860/vonc

Answer (score 1):

In order to decoupling the reception of the message from the client and the actual processing you have different options. In fact, the one you outlined is quite good.

Conceptually, you could try something like the following.

Upon reception of a new HTTP request from your client, the server will provide that client some type of unique identifier, ideally in a `202`, `Accepted` response. This unique identifier will be used later by the client to retrieve the actual result.

In addition, instead of invoking directly the OpenAI API, your server could publish a new message in a [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) topic. The required SDK is provided for different programming languages, [Python](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library#pubsub-client-libraries-python) among them.

The published message must include the unique identifier returned to the client and all the necessary information to perform the ChatGCP computation.

For example:

```py
import uuid
from app.forms_prompt import PromptForm
from app.models import ModelName
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# You must provide the right project and topic values
project_id = "your-project-id"
topic_id = "your-topic-id"

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)


@login_required
def form_prompt(request: HttpRequest, pk: int) -> HttpResponse:
    instance = get_object_or_404(ModelName, pk=pk)
    form = PromptForm(request.POST or None, instance=setkeyword)
    # check if form data is valid
    if form.is_valid():
        prompt = form.cleaned_data["text"]
        request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        message = {
            "request_id": request_id,
            "prompt": prompt
        }

        data = json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8")
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
        # future.result will return the message id generated by 
        # Pub/Sub, unique within your topic
        print(future.result())

        form.save()
        return render(request, "view_computing_prompt", context={"request_id": request_id}, status=202)
    return render(request, "view_prompt_name.html", context)
```

To perform this actual OpenAI API call you can define a cloud function [triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) when new messages arrive to the configured Pub/Sub topic.

This Cloud Function should store the result of the computation performed by ChatGPT, when ready, in some type of storage. This storage should accesible to the server as well: it is necessary to check if the result is available when the client ask for it.

The actual storage mechanism in which the ChatGCP result should be stored will depend on your actual implementation.

For example, you could use a [relational database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) table and insert a record with the unique identifier returned by the client and the actual result provided.

Or something such as [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/), keying your content by the unique identifier provided initially to the client.

Or you can use a Cloud Storage bucket and create and entry with name equals to the unique identifier provided to the client and, as content, the result provided by the ChatGPT API: it could be a cost effective solution.

Consider the following code as a reference of the function implementation, based on your own code and the provided [Cloud Function Pub/Sub GCP example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub)

```py
import openai
import base64

from cloudevents.http import CloudEvent
import functions_framework


def subscribe(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    message = json.loads(base64.b64decode(cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]).decode())
    prompt = message['prompt']
    # consider configuring a secret for storing the OpenAI API key
    # https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets
    openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_KEY")
    
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
               model="gpt-4",
               messages=[
                  {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
               ],
    )

    content = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]

    request_id = message['request_id']

    # as mentioned, storage the message in some place accesible 
    # to both the function and the django server
    # see, for example, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects-from-memory
    # ...
```

Please, do not forget to configure the appropriate permissions for the different products described above for both the server and the cloud function as required.

You mentioned in the answer comments that you reached the `1024` per attribute value limit imposed by Pub/Sub. Yes, certainly it is a hard limit you should be aware of. To bypass it, you can try the following:

- Try reengineering your prompt. `1024` bytes is not too much, but it should be enough for a normal input provided by a user. Delegate to the Cloud Function in charge of performing the actual ChatGPT invocation the responsibility of composing a well formed prompt, in which the input provided by the user is constrained, restricted, fitting only a minimal part of the prompt finally provided to the ChatGPT API.
- If necessary, use Cloud Storage for storing a text object with content, the prompt provided by the user, and give Pub/Sub the path to that object.
- If your data is suitable, it should be in your use case, try compressing the prompt provided.

Comment: i will test your solution as well, I do not know if I can accept both answers or no, I am so thankful for your great help

Comment: Thank you very much, as you wish. Please, in any case, it is not necessary: I just mentioned in the @VonC answer comments that the answer, although correct, don't take advantage of more suitable technologies that GCP offers, in my opinion, for implementing your solution.

Comment: i faced this problem: the maximum allowed is 1024. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas for more information, it seems that the prompt is so long for the publisher to send ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @ladhari. I updated the answer to provide possible workarounds to your problem. I hope it helps.